# Change template 'product-category' of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I edit the template page of categories in WooCommerce? I need to customize the title and the breadcrumbs.

I tried to edit `content-product_cat.php` file. But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you changed in that file as that file only consists li and few hooks ? can you post your code to understand it better ?

Comment: Al archive pages use archive-products.php template where you will need to make changes using available hooks or by overriding the template herself or the child templates. for breadcumps is just one template for all woocommerce. Your question is just unclear as you don't give any details about what you are trying to do and there is no code.